# What mistake have I made in showing these automorphisms generate the group $D_8$?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

In my lecture notes it says that the group generated by the automorphisms $\sigma(t)=it, \tau(t)=\tfrac{1}{t}, G=<\sigma,\tau>$ is the Dihedral 8 Group .

Now $D_8=<\sigma,\tau|\sigma^4=\tau^2=1, \tau \sigma \tau^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}>$

And we see that:

$\sigma^4=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(t))))=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(it)))=\sigma(\sigma(-t))=\sigma(-it)=t$

$\tau(\tau(t))=\tau(\tfrac{1}{t})=t$

But for the final condition that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}$ I seem to be making a mistake . First we note that $\tau^{-1}(t)=\tau(t)=\tfrac{1}{t}$, while $\sigma^{-1}(t)=-it$

I get that

$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}(t)=\tau \sigma (\tfrac{1}{t})=\tau(\tfrac{1}{it})=it$

What mistake am I making ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is it should be $\sigma (\tfrac{1}{t})=(i\tfrac{1}{t}),$ not $\tfrac{1}{it}$

Comment: so $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(t)=\tau \sigma (\dfrac{1}{t})=\tau(\dfrac i t)=\dfrac t i = -i t = \sigma^{-1}(t)$